# Noob:: would someone be helpful to be sure I am as private as possible?

Tags: configuration, anonymity, relays, private

I follow all of the usual set ups, but in global it shows my external ip and the name of my isp. Is this normal? Am I putting myself out there more than I need to?
Thank you for your patience. 
[link to globe page](https://globe.torproject.org/#/relay/8DFCA6CB38C1D9636958D71F3221C18B64604C72)

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a relay. (If this was your intention, then thank you!)

Running a relay is not private / anonymous, it is public. Your IP needs to be public, so that other relays can connect to you to build circuits. So your Tor is now part of the Tor network.
Running a relay is not to keep yourself anonymous. It is to help others stay anonymous.

If this was not your intention, you should edit or comment to your post to explain what you were trying to do (just browse through Tor, browse .onion sites, setup a Tor proxy for your network to use, ...).

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is my intention to run the relay, I browse tor from my computer / iPhone using the browser but use my rpi to run the relay. I fully support the service and find it vital- I cant afford the minatory donation but I want to contribute to a service I use. I am not using the rpi to browse, just headless for the relay. I am new to this I just want to be sure I am ' 'covering' myself from easy mistakes. Also, I want to run it as effectively/ efficiently as possible to be of best assistance. I know this is a peer project, but is there any possibility of c&v code to have

Comment: @Caravaggio make an Exit node out of your relay, and allow ports ALL ports except 25,465,137-139 - mail ports and Windows old-known ports. A traffic stream will be enough due to high demand for exits, and your traffic - protected by SSL/TLS/HTTPS, of course - will be deluded up to almost impossible to extract from a stream.